# How to find whether one record column value exits in another table or not?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables, one is `T1` and another `T2`, below is the `T1` sample:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| x1 | y1 |
| x2 | y2 |
| x2 | y4 |
| x3 | y3 |

and `T2` contains:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | y1 | 1 |
| x2 | y2 | 2 |
| x2 | y4 | 2 |
| x3 | y3 | 1 |
| x3 | y2 | 2 |

I hope to query the data `T1 column 1` is in `T2 column 1`  but `T1 column 2` not in `T2 column 2` .
The purpose is like, table `T1` is the `key-value` table, all records in `T1` should be checked whether exist in `T2` with specific `key-value`. If not in `T2`, then should be queried. Means the record in `T2`:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x3 | y2 | 2 |

should be displayed.

Comment: Your results do not correspond to your description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #T1
CREATE TABLE #T1(Col1 VARCHAR(10), Col2 VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #T1 (Col1, Col2) VALUES 
('x1', 'y1'),
('x2', 'y2'),
('x2', 'y4'),
('x3', 'y3')

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #T2
CREATE TABLE #T2(Col1 VARCHAR(10), Col2 VARCHAR(10), Col3 VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #T2 (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES 
('x1', 'y1', '1'),
('x2', 'y2', '2'),
('x2', 'y4', '2'),
('x3', 'y3', '1'),
('x3', 'y2', '2')
```

This query should work

```
SELECT #T2.*
FROM #T2
INNER JOIN #T1 ON #T1.Col1 = #T2.Col1 AND #T1.Col2 != #T2.Col2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #T1 WHERE #T2.Col1 = #T1.Col1 AND #T2.Col2 = #T1.Col2)
```

Result:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x3 | y2 | 2 |

Comment: I think I did not make the question very clear so I have updated the question.

Comment: @EricGong That query still works. Please see updated answer with example.

Comment: I have added 2 records in T1 and T2, which column 1 = x2 and column 2 = y4, according to your answer, x2 y2 & x2 y4 will also appear.

Comment: @EricGong I got your point. Please see the updated answer according to your updated question.

Comment: @EricGong If the answer helped you, then feel free to mark the answer as correct. That way, other users can find it right away.

Answer (score 0):

> T1 column 1 is in T2 column 1 but T1 column 2 not in T2 column 2

I assume you mean that `col1` matches between the two tables but `col1`/`col2` does not.

You seem to want `not exists` and `exists`

```
select t2.*
from t2
where not exists (select 1
                  from t1
                  where t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2
                 ) and
      exists (select 1
              from t1
              where t1.col1 = t2.col1
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the records from a `table` that is not common to other `table`

```
SELECT T2.*
FROM T2
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM T1
WHERE T1.C1=T2.C1 AND T1.C2=T2.C2)
```